# Three.js - Bake skeleton transform into geometry

Tags: three.js, 3d

What is the proper way of applying [`bone`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Bone) matrices to vertices so that the actual geometry represents the transformed shape without using GPU?

I have a character model I am applying a [`skeleton`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Skeleton) to that I want to 3D print in different poses, so I want to use the [`STLExporter`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/exporters/STLExporter.js) to export a 3D printable file, but it only exports the original geometry.

If I can [`scene.traverse()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D.traverse) over each [`SkinnedMesh`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/SkinnedMesh) and [`geometry.applyMatrix(???)`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry.applyMatrix) with the correct bone matrix in the right order, I should be able to export an STL with the transform applied, right?

```js
var objects = [];
var triangles = 0;
scene.traverse( function ( object ) {
    if ( object.isMesh ) {
        var geometry = object.geometry;
        if ( geometry.isBufferGeometry ) {
            geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( geometry );
        }
        // TODO: Apply skeleton transform
        if ( geometry.isGeometry ) {
            triangles += geometry.faces.length;
            objects.push( {
                geometry: geometry,
                matrixWorld: object.matrixWorld
            } );
        }
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 3):

have a look at this pull request: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/8953/files

Especially this part:

```
THREE.SkinnedMesh.prototype.boneTransform = 
...snip...
for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i ++ ) {
+
+           var skinWeight = skinWeights[ properties[ i ] ];
+
+           if ( skinWeight != 0 ) {
+
+               var boneIndex = skinIndices[ properties[ i ] ];
+               tempMatrix.multiplyMatrices( this.skeleton.bones[ boneIndex ].matrixWorld, this.skeleton.boneInverses[ boneIndex ] );
+               result.add( temp.copy( clone ).applyMatrix4( tempMatrix ).multiplyScalar( skinWeight ) );
+
+           }
+
+       }
```

So to bake the deformations you have to do the following steps:

1. Go over all vertices
2. Get their corresponding `skinIndices` and `skinWeights`
3. Get the associated bones for each vertex and their weights
4. Go over all bones
5. Get the transform matrix of the bone and translate it to the coordinate system of the `Geometry`
6. Weight the matrix via the associated `skinWeights[boneIdx]`
7. Apply the final matrix

edit: A version of the exporter that fixes the issue. (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/1be00d5ad075b2305b86c6385403d0e56b4621dd/examples/js/exporters/STLExporter.js)

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for answering my question. It looks like I have some work to do to adapt that code.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation quasi.
@wizulus have you managed to get this incorporated into the exporter.
If not I will try my best in the upcoming weeks as I currently have the exact same problem you described above. The STL exporter in the current master just ignores all the bone transforms on skinnedMesh vertices. 
https://gist.github.com/jcarletto27/e271bbb7639c4bed2427 This is a solution for an older version but since the skinIndices and skinWeights are stored differently, probably due to the new animation system, this does not work anymore.

Comment: I made a version of the exporter that works with the current master and incorporates vertex bone transformations on SkinnedMesh objects.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/1be00d5ad075b2305b86c6385403d0e56b4621dd/examples/js/exporters/STLExporter.js

Answer (score 2):

Baking in the scene with normals preservation and without exporting to STL.

Usage:

`bakeSkeleton(mesh)`

The transformation will be applied to the provided object and all its children. `getBoneNormalTransform` is made from built-in `boneTransform`  on `SkinnedMesh` but adapted for normals.

```js
function bakeSkeleton ( target ) {
  var v1 = new Vector3();

  target.traverse( function ( object ) {
    if ( !object.isSkinnedMesh ) return;
    if ( object.geometry.isBufferGeometry !== true ) throw new Error( 'Only BufferGeometry supported.' );

    var positionAttribute = object.geometry.getAttribute( 'position' );
    var normalAttribute = object.geometry.getAttribute( 'normal' );

    for ( var j = 0; j < positionAttribute.count; j ++ ) {
      object.boneTransform( j, v1 );
      positionAttribute.setXYZ( j, v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);

      getBoneNormalTransform.call( object, j, v1 );
      normalAttribute.setXYZ( j, v1.x, v1.y, v1.z );
    }

    positionAttribute.needsUpdate = true;
    normalAttribute.needsUpdate = true;

    object.skeleton.bones.forEach(bone => bone.rotation.set(0,0,0));
  } );
}


const getBoneNormalTransform = (function () {

  var baseNormal = new Vector3();

  var skinIndex = new Vector4();
  var skinWeight = new Vector4();

  var vector = new Vector3();
  var matrix = new Matrix4();
  var matrix3 = new Matrix3();

  return function ( index, target ) {

    var skeleton = this.skeleton;
    var geometry = this.geometry;

    skinIndex.fromBufferAttribute( geometry.attributes.skinIndex, index );
    skinWeight.fromBufferAttribute( geometry.attributes.skinWeight, index );

    baseNormal.fromBufferAttribute( geometry.attributes.normal, index ).applyNormalMatrix( matrix3.getNormalMatrix(this.bindMatrix) );

    target.set( 0, 0, 0 );

    for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i ++ ) {

      var weight = skinWeight.getComponent( i );

      if ( weight !== 0 ) {

        var boneIndex = skinIndex.getComponent( i );

        matrix.multiplyMatrices( skeleton.bones[ boneIndex ].matrixWorld, skeleton.boneInverses[ boneIndex ] );

        target.addScaledVector( vector.copy( baseNormal ).applyNormalMatrix( matrix3.getNormalMatrix(matrix) ), weight );

      }

    }
    matrix3.getNormalMatrix(this.bindMatrixInverse);
    return target.applyNormalMatrix( matrix3 );

  };

}())
```

Comment: I think this code is broken. Don't you have to update the contents of `v1` before calling `object.boneTransform( j, v1 )`?

Comment: @KyleLin boneTransform and getBoneNormalTransform use v1 as a target for computations

Comment: I understand that `v1` is the target for the computation, but `boneTransform` needs a bone index (which you provide with `j`) and an original input vector to transform, does it not?

Comment: @KyleLin no, boneTransform only writes data into the target and it doesn't read any value from it. There might've been an api change in Three as I see there's a function called `applyBoneTransform` which works differently and it transforms the value from the target